# In HTML, what is the name of this attribute?

Tags: c#, html

I have this line of HTML:

```
<a class="thrida" id="txtTehtav" name="txtTehtav" style="visibility: visible;">3+5=</a>
```

I'm trying to use this line **in C#** to read the value "3+5=":

```
wb.Document.GetElementById("txtTehtav").GetAttribute("value");
```

However I don't know what is the name of the attribute witch includes "3+5=".
I have already tried value and name, but those do not work.

All I want to know is the name of this attribute.

Comment: ``GetElementById("txtTehtav").innerHtml`` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an attribute, so you shouldn't try to get it using `GetAttribute`. You can get the inner text using the [`InnerText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innerhtml(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
string text = wb.Document.GetElementById("txtTehtav").InnerText; // "3+5="
```

If you want to get the HTML markup inside your tag, in case you have nested tags, you can use the [`InnerHtml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innerhtml(v=vs.110).aspx) property instead. In your case, they will have the same value.

Comment: innerText is not a standard. textContent is safer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: @daniel This is C#, not JavaScript